# Transparent panel doesn't updates its background after being moved/dragged in wxPython

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working with python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on Windows 8 OS.

The code provided below simply creates a transparent panel named as `myPanel` that contains a button. The transparent panel is created on a `mainPanel` which contains an image as a background.
The transparent panel can be dragged around in the frame.

**Problem**: After dragging the transparent panel I observed that the background of the transparent panel is not updated automatically. How to update it automatically? `How ever if I minimize the gui window and restore it again, the background of the transparent panel is updated automatically!` I don't understand the reason of this affect?
I tried using `Refresh()`, `Update()` etc. in `MouseUp(self, e)` method, but unfortunately nothing helped.
Here are the screenshots of the app. The initial state is shown in the image below when the app starts:

[image: initial]

After dragging the transparent panel, the background is not updated as shown in the image below:

[image: AfterDrag]

After minimizing the app window and then restoring it, you'll notice that the background of the transparent panel is updated automatically as shown in the image below:

[image]

**Code**: The image used in the code can be downloaded from here. [globe.jpg](https://db.tt/yEvYPMBv)

```
import wx

class gui(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.d = d = {}
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(260,260), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.mainPanel = mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainSizer = mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.myPanel = myPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, size=(80,80))
        button1 = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, size=(30,30), pos=(10,10))
        button1.SetBackgroundColour('#fff111')
        mainSizer.Add(myPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.MouseDown)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MouseMove)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.MouseUp)
        image_file = 'globe.jpg'
        bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        wx.StaticBitmap(mainPanel, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
        mainPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MouseMove)
        mainPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.MouseUp)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainPanel.Layout()

    def MouseDown(self, e):   
        o = e.GetEventObject()
        sx,sy = self.mainPanel.ScreenToClient(o.GetPositionTuple())
        dx,dy = self.mainPanel.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
        o._x,o._y = (sx-dx, sy-dy)
        self.d['d'] = o

    def MouseMove(self, e):
        try:
            if 'd' in self.d:
                o = self.d['d']
                x, y = wx.GetMousePosition()
                o.SetPosition(wx.Point(x+o._x,y+o._y))
        except: pass

    def MouseUp(self, e):
        try:
            if 'd' in self.d: del self.d['d']
        except: pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom panel and then draw a portion of the globe on that panel based on where it's located on top of the parent frame.  This method "fakes" the transparency.  I've included an example below.

```
import wx

class CustomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,-1,size=(80,80))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)


    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        parentw,parenth = self.GetParent().GetSize()

        image = wx.Image('globe.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        x,y = self.GetPosition()
        mywidth,myheight = self.GetSize()

        if x + mywidth >= parentw:
            mywidth = parentw - x
        if y + myheight >= parenth:
            myheight = parenth - y

        drawx = 0
        drawy = 0

        if x < 0:
            drawx = abs(x)
            x = 0
        if y < 0:
            drawy = abs(y)
            y = 0

        r = wx.Rect(x,y,mywidth,myheight)

        try:
            image = image.GetSubImage(r)
        except:
            # rectangle is out of parent
            print 'rect ',r ,' is out of parent frame'
            return 

        bitmap = image.ConvertToBitmap()

        pdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        pdc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, drawx, drawy)

class gui(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.d = d = {}
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(260,260), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.mainPanel = mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainSizer = mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #self.myPanel = myPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, size=(80,80))
        self.myPanel = myPanel = CustomPanel(mainPanel)
        button1 = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, size=(30,30), pos=(10,10))
        button1.SetBackgroundColour('#fff111')

        button2 = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, size=(30,30), pos=(40,40))
        button2.SetBackgroundColour('#fff111')


        mainSizer.Add(myPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.MouseDown)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MouseMove)
        myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.MouseUp)
        image_file = 'globe.jpg'
        bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        wx.StaticBitmap(mainPanel, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))

        mainPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MouseMove)
        mainPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.MouseUp)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainPanel.Layout()

    def MouseDown(self, e):   
        o = e.GetEventObject()
        sx,sy = self.mainPanel.ScreenToClient(o.GetPositionTuple())
        dx,dy = self.mainPanel.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
        o._x,o._y = (sx-dx, sy-dy)
        self.d['d'] = o

    def MouseMove(self, e):
        try:
            if 'd' in self.d:
                o = self.d['d']
                x, y = wx.GetMousePosition()
                o.SetPosition(wx.Point(x+o._x,y+o._y))
                self.myPanel.Refresh()
        except: pass


    def MouseUp(self, e):
        try:
            if 'd' in self.d: del self.d['d']
        except: pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: +1, Well this is a clever & bit complicated solution! Unfortunately it has some issues. 1. When the button is moved near to the border of the image, then the background is not updated? 2. Adding a second button creates a problem too? I tested on Windows 8 pro, python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0

Comment: I added some code to fix the clipping issue around the borders.  What issue are you seeing with a second button?

Comment: Thanks, the clipping issue is solved. The buttons should be able to move independently. Currently button1 and button2 move together. In my real life app, I have many buttons about 20 of them and I have to move them independent of each other.

Comment: That's a lot of buttons.  I don't think this approach will work for 20 buttons because they are all associated with a panel which needs to be bigger than the button for a drag and drop to work.  Have you seen the wxPython demo program?  There's an example in there called "DragImage".  That would be my approach to solving this kind of problem.  The demo code is free to modify and you would only have to change your source images and the mouse events slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look. I think there must be a simple solution to my problem, it must be some thing related to simply refresh or to update the app window. I don't understand what actually happens when I minimize and restore my app window, because after doing so my problem is solved automatically(the background changes automatically). Now, I just need to find something similar in wxPython to make this effect.